# Find repeated match in the same entry

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
|  id  |  text                                                   |
|  1   |  <tm>park</tm> .... <tm>asdad</tm> ... <tm>park</tm>    |
|  2   | ..... <tm>test</tm> .....
                               ........
```

Is it possible to find the repeated `<tm>` (in this case `<tm>park</tm>`) tags inside the same column in *pure* SQL or do I need some extra code to parse the table ?

Thank you

Comment: you can try backreferences as in `.*(blah).*\1`, \1 represents the string matched by the first capturing group (the first expression between parentheses).

Comment: Thanks I got it working. If you create an answer with that I will  accept it.